# Grant only DDL permissions for Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have a user/role (lets call that role `migration_assistant`) in my DB that I want to grant exlusively DDL permissions within my schema.

specifically `migration_assistant` should be able to `CREATE` new tables and `ALTER` existing ones. But it should not be able to `DELETE` tables or `DROP` a database etc.

Any idea how to accomplish that?

Comment: You cannot do that with PostgreSQL's permission system. Try an event trigger.

Comment: From the manual: "You must own the table to use ALTER TABLE. ". That means you can also drop the table. But you could also drop all columns and that would create almost the same situation, no more data and most likely a mismatch between the application and database.